Existence of symplectic form on $\mathbb{S}^1$-trivial bundle of canonical fillings of Kahler surface.
Suppose $(\Sigma, j, \omega)$ be a noncompact Kahler surface without boundary, and suppose $M$ be a canonical filling of $\Sigma$ Which means that $M$ is a $3$-dimensional noncompact manifold with boundary $\partial M = \Sigma$ and having a zero $3$-homology.
Then, here is the question.
Suppose $N(\partial M)$ be a collar of $\partial M$.

Does $M \times \mathbb{S}^1$ have a symplectic form $\Omega$ which satisfies $\Omega|N(\partial (M \times \mathbb{S}^1)) = \pi^*_{\partial M} \omega + \pi_M^* \alpha \wedge \mathrm{d} \theta$ (where $\theta$ is a canonical coordinate along $\mathbb{S}^1$) for some $1$-form $\alpha$ on $M$?

If $\Sigma = \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ and $M = \mathbb{D}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$, then there is a way to do this. But I don't think it holds for general case.
